# Как узнать является ли хэш частью merkle root?

Tags: хеширование

Есть произвольный хэш и корень merkle root.
Собственно сам вопрос - как узнать является искомый хэш частью merkle root?
Без поиска по дереву, именно был ли ранее включен наш хэш в merkle root или нет?

Существует ли способов свести все хэши к одному хэшу и проверить есть ли искомый в финальном хэше?

Comment: Так как дерево хешей не является деревом поиска, вам придётся просмотреть все узлы дерева.

Comment: Существует ли способов свести все хэши к одному хэшу и проверить есть ли искомый в финальном хэше?

Comment: Вы просите сжать 1000 хешей в один и оставить возможность проверки? Это невозможно. Вы можете все хеши из дерева хешей переписать в поисковое дерево, тогда проверка вхождения займёт логарифм. При должной ловкости оба дерева (хешей и поисковое) можно обновлять вместе тоже за логарифм.